# Returning strings vs integers?

Tags: php, function, return, return-value

Suppose I have a function called `checkTemperature($temp)` that can return three different possibilities:

1. too hot
2. OK
3. too cold

Would you return integers, such as `-1, 0, 1` or `1, 2, 3` (etc..) or strings, such as the above?

What is considered the best practice?

Comment: Using an enumeration would make your code more readable.

Comment: Depends on what you want to do with the returned data.

Comment: return what ever makes sense to you within the context of the application

Comment: depends on how you want to return the result, as a string(descriptive) or as a integer(specific).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You would typically use enums, but PHP doesn't straight up have support for an enum construct. However, we can certainly emulate them.

```
class Temperatures
{
    const TooHot = 1;
    const OK = 2;
    const TooCold = 3;
}
```

Then you can do

```
return Temperatures::TooHot;
```

And compare

```
if ($retval == Temperatures::OK)
```

The value you assign your variables is not really important, as long as they are different. You can use the values for something interesting depending on your app and context.

Comment: +1 This is ultimately more *readable* and straightforward if you support OOP. Otherwise, I'd advocate returning strings.

Comment: I just tried doing this, but when I define "public const TooHot = 1;" I get the error "unexpected public keyword." I need to call functions from other classes, so if constants cannot be made public in php (?) then your method will not work?

Comment: Constants are public already, no need for public keyword (error has explained you all). In @Xeon06 example, where do you see public const TooHot = 1; ???

Answer (score 2):

-1 is usually a reference to "not found" or invalid reading in conventions I've encountered. Strings are easily understood and there are many methods to assign a string to a numerical value. For example too cold = -100, too hot = 100, just right = 75.

I would vote string over integer on this one.

Comment: Yes! Another vote for enums above me. @Xeon06 Good call man.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I tend to go with numeric and comparable where it makes sense.  Adding constants to the class to avoid the 'magic numbers' effect.

```
<?php

if ($result == 2) { ... }
// vs 
if ($result == Temp::TOO_HOT) { ... }

// Though can result in some odd code
if ($result > Temp::OK) { echo "that's bad"; }
```

Answer (score 0):

For less overhead you could use `#define`

```
define('TEMP_HOT',  1);
define('TEMP_OK',   2);
define('TEMP_COLD', 3);
```

It only makes sense to use a class if you already do so.

Answer (score -1):

there is not 'best practice' in this case. in some cases returning a string will make more sense while other times an integer will do the job